# SkipWhile TakeWhile, then take also lines above until a match

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` to gather lines from a large file using `Linq`.

```
var foundLines = File.ReadLines(filePath).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("pattern1")).TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("pattern2"));
```

But I also want the text above the lines I gathered until another string match. Is this possible?

I'll try to show this visually. I only have `pattern1`, this variable is given. `pattern2` and `pattern3` are static data.

```
...
...
...pattern3...
...
...
...pattern1...
...
...
...pattern2...
...
...
```

The text between pattern1 and pattern2 is what I can simply catch by doing `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` on `File.ReadLines`. After this is catched, I need to go up and catch all data until `pattern3`.

So the whole data I want to catch is from `pattern3` until `pattern2`. But my starting point must be `pattern1` because that info (ID) is given and data changes based on that.

For example:

`Pattern1` is an ID, or a GUID: KFK284NSKQLOFIE8.

`Pattern2` is "end processing"

`Pattern3` is "start processing"

And I need all lines between "start processing" and "end processing"

If this is not possible with `Linq`, how can I solve this problem? Would `FileStream.Seek` be an option?

Comment: Why you cannot "grab" lines starting from `pattern3` while "waiting" for `pattern1` and when you rich `pattern2` append it to the pattern1 collection.

Comment: @Fabio thanks for your comment, can I do this with `Linq`?  Maybe I can use `Regular expressions`? something like: last occurence of "start processing" until the ID match would be the condition for my `SkipWhile`. EDIT: I don't think that is possible, because my Linq expression is line by line, and regex would have been a multiline match

Comment: Would reading all the lines of the file into an array make things easier ? I think this is more of a case of keeping track of what 'state' you're in when you're going through the lines.

Comment: @auburg That's a good point, but the files I'm reading will be at least 500 MB. These would give out of memory exceptions, I need to load only small piece every read, and it needs to be very performant. Because `File.ReadLines` is very fast, I wanted to use that

Comment: I suggest you benchmark reading everything into memory since searching an in memory list would be much, much faster than searching a file. I also think it would make your implementation easier.

Comment: @auburg, Loading 1 GB into memory is not the way to go I think. there must be ways to sequentially load pieces and process.

Comment: I think @Fabio's suggestion is valid - if you reach pattern3 start collecting data at that point, so that once you have everything between pattern 1 and pattern 2, there's no need to 'seek' back up to pattern3. Or is it not possible to recognise pattern3 until you know what pattern1 is ?

Comment: @auburg I can recognize `pattern3`, but in the large file, there will be thousands of it. it's `pattern1` that will find the unique place in the file.

Comment: From your comments the problem is more advanced then you state in your question. The fact that `pattern3` (and `pattern2`?) Can occur multiple times matters a lot. Also you ask about a `Linq` solution but then in the comments state that performance and memory usage are very important, which would indicate it might be better not to use `Linq` (imo `Linq` is more convenience and less performance)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.  Used code like this for a very long time and I feel is the best method. Each capture is a single string in the List object data.  I can modify code to change the format of Data if required.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string line = "";
            Boolean foundPattern3 = false;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("pattern3"))
                {
                    data.Add(line);
                    foundPattern3 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line.Contains("pattern2"))
                    {
                        foundPattern3 = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (foundPattern3)
                        {
                            data[data.Count() - 1] += "\n" + line;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it needs to be something like that yes. Files.ReadLines uses StreamReader in the background anyway. And I didn't counter any performance loss.

Comment: But don't forget to dispose StreamReader ;)